# c++ std::set compare function when object is member of the set

Tags: c++, set, compare

I have a set composed of objects; in order to work the `operator<` must be defined for ordering the objects inside the set. If I define the `operator<` as a friend function, it works; if I define the `operator<` as a member function I get the error:

> Error  C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand >operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

I do not understand why the version of `operator<` implemented as member function does not work/what should be changed about it.
I provide bellow a simplified example of the problem case:

```
class TestObj
{
private: 
    int m_a;
public:
    TestObj(int a): m_a{a} {}
    /* operator < as friend function works */
    /*friend bool operator< (const TestObj& t1, const TestObj& t2)
    {
        return t1.m_a < t2.m_a;
    }*/
    /* operator < as member function does not work! */
    bool operator< (const TestObj& t2)
    {
        return m_a < t2.m_a;
    }
};
void testSetCompare()
{
    std::set<TestObj> set1;
    set1.insert(10);
    set1.insert(20);
}
```

I do not understand why the version of `operator<` implemented as member function does not work/what should be changed about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the member function `const`. Because you declared it as 'non-const' the compiler cannot decide if your operator will change `*this`, and therefore your operator cannot be used when you have a `const TestObj&`.

```
bool operator< (const TestObj& t2) const
{
    return m_a < t2.m_a;
}
```

It will do the job.

Edit: The "No acceptable converson" means that it cannot convert from `const TestObj&` to `TestObj&` because it would break the rules of `const` (and your operator needs a `TestObj&`).